# How do I create a LocalDateTime instance?

Tags: java, variables, localdate, localtime

If I only have the year, month and day, how do I initialize a [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instance?

If I have to include time, I will just set it to 00:00:00.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--

Comment: Check out the documentation of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). It provides multiple static methods for creating instances, just use `0` for arguments pertaining to time.

Comment: "Include tme"? What do you mean? Could you please provide some samle input and the expected outcome? It´s pretty unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

The elegant way goes through a `LocalDate`:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 18).atStartOfDay();
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2020-01-18T00:00

If you’ve got the month as a number, like 1 for January, use `LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 18)` instead. The rest is the same.

**Think twice before using `LocalDateTime`**. We usually use date and time together for establishing a point in time. `LocalDateTime` is unsuited for that (some will say that it can’t). Why and how? It doesn’t know any time zone or offset from UTC. So any person and any piece of software reading the `LocalDateTime` is free to interpret it into any time zone they happen to think of and not the intended one. For at least 19 out of 20 purposes you’re better off with either a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`. For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Recife");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 18).atStartOfDay(zone);
```

> 2020-01-18T00:00-03:00[America/Recife]

The `-03:00` between the minutes and the zone ID is the offset from UTC. Now we’re leaving no room for misinterpretation.